# Embed child in child of a custom type

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I'm creating a custom type in QML that has a `Column` inside a `GroupBox`. When users of the type add components to `CustomType`, they should be inside the `Column`, not `GroupBox`. How can this be achieved without making extra wrapper files?

```
//CustomType.qml

GroupBox {
    Column {

    }
}


//Main.qml

CustomType {
    CheckBox {//This should be inside the Column of the GroupBox in CustomType   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `property alias` for the children of the `GroupBox` in `CustomType.qml` and declare it to be the `default` property, like this:

```
//CustomType.qml

GroupBox {
    default property alias children: body.children

    Column {
        id: body
    }
}
```

Whenever you add items to a `CustomType`, they will go into the `Column`.